# How to use the information stored in mutableStateOf in Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have information in `json` and I retrieve it using `retrofit2`, everything works fine, I get the data in a List.

I need this information to fill elements in Jetpack Compose for which I use `mutableStateOf` to save the states.

My function that I use is the following:

```
fun jsonParsing(
    dataRecox: MutableState<List<Event>>
) {
    val TAG_LOGS = "Mariox"
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://myserversample.com/pGet/track/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
    val retrofitAPI = retrofit.create(APIService1::class.java)
    retrofitAPI.getRecolector().enqueue(object : Callback<List<Event>> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<List<Event>>,
            response: Response<List<Event>>
        ) {
            val data = response.body()
            val mydata = data!!
            dataRecox.value = mydata
            Log.i(TAG_LOGS, Gson().toJson(data))
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Event>>, t: Throwable) {
            t.printStackTrace()
        }
    })
}
```

Mymodel:

```
data class Event (

    val deviceID : Int,
    val statusCode : Int,
    val accountID : String,
    val speedKPH : Int,
       .
       .
       .
}
```

My composable:

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    val dataRecox = remember {
        mutableStateOf(emptyList<Event>())
    }

    jsonParsing(dataRecox)

    println("======")

    println(dataRecox) // ok data
    println(dataRecox.value). // ok data
    
    //Uncommenting println(dataRecox.value[0]) I get empty.
    //println(dataRecox.value[0])

    //Text(text = dataRecox.value[0].uniqueID)
}
```

When I do not use the information in the console, by calling `Greeting("Android")` all the data is printed correctly:

[image: no error]

The problem comes when I want to use that information:

For example, if I want to print in console `println(dataRecox.value[0])` here it returns empty. If I want to use it with a composable Text: `Text(text = dataRecox.value[0].uniqueID)` it also gives me empty.
[image: image sample with error]

Can someone explain to me why this happens, because when I start using the information the data becomes empty.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're doing is totally different of the recommended way... here's my suggestion.

1. Define a class to represent the screen's state.

```kotlin
data class ScreenState(
    val events: List<Event> = emptyList(),
    val error: Throwable? = null
)
```

2. Use a ViewModel to perform the API request and keep the screen state.

```kotlin
class EventsViewModel : ViewModel()
    private val _screenState = MutableStateFlow<ScreenState>(ScreenState())
    val screenState = _screenState.asStateFlow()

    init {
        jsonParsing()
    }

    fun jsonParsing() {
        val TAG_LOGS = "Mariox"
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://myserversample.com/pGet/track/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        val retrofitAPI = retrofit.create(APIService1::class.java)
        retrofitAPI.getRecolector().enqueue(object : Callback<List<Event>> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<Event>>,
                response: Response<List<Event>>
            ) {
                val data = response.body()
                Log.i(TAG_LOGS, Gson().toJson(data))
                _screenState.update {
                    ScreenState(it.events)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Event>>, t: Throwable) {
                t.printStackTrace()
                _screenState.update {
                    ScreenState(error = t)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

3. Instantiate the ViewModel and use it in your screen...

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    val vm = viewModel<EventsViewModel>()
    val screenState by vm.screenState.observeAsState()

    LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        items(screenState.items) {
            Text(it. accountID)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can have the business logic written in `viewModel`
- Observe a state in the `commpose` layer.
- You can assign the variable to a `mutableState` if the value of the state changes.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Demo() {
    val currentValue = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("Undefined") }
    // Here you can assign the currentValue by observing the state from view-model
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center, horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically, horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Button(onClick = { currentValue.value = "Netflix" }) { Text(text = "Netflix") }
        }
        Text(text = currentValue.value)
    }
    Log.d("POKEMON", "Current Value --> ${currentValue.value}")
}
```

- Basically we use the mutable state to have an update value stored in the composable if needed.
- Better approach is to lift up the state to `view-model` and observe the state in the composable.